# How can I get average of each item in a mysql row

Tags: mysql, database

I am learning database queries in command prompt.

Can you guys please help me to find out the query that can be used in this :

Display the name of all products with their rate and increased rate by 20%.

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: At the least, show the table schema and any queries you have tried.

Comment: This is more like cheating than learning

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT product_name,  
       rate,  
       (rate + (rate*0.2)) as  "Increased-rate"
  FROM product;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of asking questions, you should try and update the post with what you tried.

Here is an online sample SQL database with ready made data, try queries yourself and learn from website.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_op_in

`Hint`: Your query to get product names, rates and 20% increase in rate would look like below (fill in the blank your self)

```
SELECT productName, price, ______ FROM Products
```

This is for your benefit!

`NOTE:` If you are looking for average of any column then read about `GROUP BY` clause and `Aggregate Functions`.